# What are the important features to use with Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, selenium-ide

I am an intern and was assigned to be a Software Tester.

Comment: Please re-phrase stating what you've already discovered, and maybe asking something with a little more detail.  In what way's do you mean.  Some people will find other features more useful than others.  For example, do you you have any programming background to actually script with, is your website using alot of dynamic elements?  Sorry, but this is just a little bit too broad of a question to be able to definitively answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Below are the Important features of Selenium IDE

1. Record and Play
2. Control the speed of execution of automation
3. Automate any web page by providing URL
4. Storing test cases/test scripts
5. Find a particular element on a web page
6. Support for several types of locators
7. Error / exception logging
8. rich set of commands

**If you are using google chrome extension then**

9. Runs Offline
10. Work with google drive

and **so many other features are there**, kindly go the **Selenium IDE book**.